# Aggregate elasticity of demand in a differentiated products market

Tags: elasticity

Is the notion of aggregate elasticity of demand applicable in a market for slightly differentiated products? Intuitively, it seems like it should. If market output can be expressed in a single number (for example, the number of cars in a market of cars differentiated by color), then if the price of each of the products is increased by the same small percentage, you could calculate an aggregate elasticity. Is this an accepted concept in economics?